# Windows XP 64-bit hangs

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, raid, freeze

I have a Windows XP x64 box showing a couple of odd behaviors. First, the system is hanging after it has been up for about ten minutes. All applications stop responding, Ctrl + Alt + Del does nothing, etc. I have to hold the power button down to shut it down.

Also, I am using Intel RAID, and I noticed that the state after POST before Windows boots shows "Verify", and Intel Storage Manager shows that it is verifying when I hover over it; however, when I open ISM, it says there are no RAID volumes. Further, when I do a System Report through ISM, it shows me again that there is a RAID volume named "Mirror" that is 1% through the verification process.

Chkdsk and sfc come back clean. I have run Memtest86+ and the RAM looks good. Where should I go from here?

Comment: Event log maybe? Not sure... it can have red herrings.

Comment: 64 bit drivers for XP are flaky at best. Good luck.

Comment: XP 64bit is beta software imho, driver support sucks also.